# C# / .NET / ASPX : Adding Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies

In my Page_Load function, I have this:

```
 var output = new StringBuilder();
        output.Append("<div class='search-recent'> <ul>");
        var str = Response.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value;
        {
            try
            {
                string[] tokens = str.Split(':');
                foreach (String searchHist in tokens)
                {
                    output.Append("<li>" + searchHist + "</li>");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                output.Append("<li>" + str + "</li>");
            }
            finally
            {
                output.Append("</div>");
                recentSearch.Text = output.ToString();
            }
        }
```

In my button function I have this:

```
if (Response.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value != null)
        {
            var oldCookieVal = Response.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value;
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
            cookie.Value = oldCookieVal + ":" + sinput;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
            cookie.Value = sinput;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        }
```

For some reason, the Cookie is always overwritten even when one exists before. Is there anyway to stop it from overwriting? Thank-you.

Reference to research: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/cookies/

Edit: It appears that the `.Value` is not returning anything, what could I use to fix this?

Big Edit: I replaced the `.Value` to `ToString();` and it now does not overwrite. However, the cookie value is `System.Web.HttpCookie` when it is sent to the front end... Any suggestions?

Front end view: https://gyazo.com/9c08160c6bca6cf5b335c0fc3861d0cb (It is all test data)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to **get** the value of the cookie as it is in the client, you need to access `Request.Cookies`.  To **set** the value, use `Response.Cookies`.

Comment: Yes but its ok to say that but how do I do that? I have tried to use `Response.Cookies` and I have tried to use `.Value` etc... Neither works, only returns `System.Web.HttpCookie` or `null`.... All I need to do now is retrieve the **Value** of the Cookie `UserSettings`

Comment: @KyleE4K Looks like you have it below.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank-you :) Apprenticeship haha, I'm a website developer, just liked the look of the Software side but managed to use Databases and now doing this on 3rd day lol Cheers though

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, so after a lot of trial and error I found that the**  `.Value` **is only used when you're setting or getting the value.**

When you want to CHECK the value exists, you remove the `.Value`.
When you want to SET or GET the value, you use `.Value`

***Example -***

***Setting the cookie (not setting or getting during the check)***

```
string oldCookieVal = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value;
        string sinput = searchInput.Text;
        if (Response.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
            cookie.Value = oldCookieVal + ":" + sinput;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
            cookie.Value = sinput;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        }
```

***Example -***

***Getting the Value and using it***

```
 var output = new StringBuilder();
        string userSettings = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value;
        output.Append("<div class='search-recent'> <ul>");
        {
            try
            {
                string[] tokens = userSettings.Split(':');
                foreach (String searchHist in tokens)
                {
                    output.Append("<li>" + searchHist + "</li>");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                output.Append("<li>" + userSettings + "</li>");
            }
            finally
            {
                output.Append("</div>");
                recentSearch.Text = output.ToString();
            }
```

**Remember to use Literal's (controls) when you're working with transferring data from back-end to front-end**